# C how to use exec with linux commands and pipes

Tags: c, exec

I need to execute the following Linux commands : ls -la | sort | wc -l and i have to use exec functions ... Here is my code:

```
x = fork();

char * args[] = { "ls", "-la" , "|", "sort" , "|" , "wc", "-l" };

if(x == 0){ //Father    
 //Dad validations


}else{      

    execlp(args[0],args[0], args[1],args[2],args[3],args[4],args[5],args[6], NULL);
    perror("Exec error\n");

    exit(1);
 }
```

The commands work properly separated, but when i put them together i get this error message:

```
  ls: cannot access |: No such file or directory

  ls: cannot access sort: No such file or directory
```

i guess the error is in the Linux pipe

Thanks for your time!

Comment: `exec(lp)` is not expecting shell syntax, it's expecting a process name and its arguments.

Comment: but you can still use exec with Linux commands... and this is what i wat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try executing the following args instead:

```
char * args[] = { "bash", "-c" , "ls -la | sort | wc -l" };
```

This is necessary because the pipe syntax you want to use (and the resulting piping of output from one process to another) is actually a feature of the shell. Thus to be able to `execlp` a command formatted in that way, we need to execute a shell (`bash` in this case) and provide your command to it as a string with the `-c` flag.

Comment: @sjl Maybe explain to Joseph why you think this will fix his problem (and that maybe he has to change the number of arguments passed to execlp)

Comment: @slj my mistake... it worked 100%, thank you! i just had to reajust my code

Comment: Thank you @AdamMartin for the suggestion. Yes, you would need to make sure you are not accessing any array elements past `args[2]` when using the updated `args` I have provided. I'm glad it helped.